# Adding the "ok glass contextual voice menu" within an immersion activity

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

Is there a way to insert the "ok, glass" trigger into an immersion activity on Glass? I want to make the launch of my application as seamless and quick as possible. Making an immersion application seemed to be the way but I can not find a way to bring up the "ok, glass" footer trigger within my activity to launch my application menu to be navigated hands free. Any clue as to how this works?

Note: I have a voice trigger to launch the app from the Glass home screen.

I'm not creating a card but rather just using an XML layout as I'm changing text on the screen dynamically to user interaction using an AsyncTask. Any advice would be great.

Comment: isn't the point of the "ok glass" command to wake the device (if needed) and only then say the extra command to launch ?

Comment: @androiddeveloper Some cards have additional options, like after taking a picture, you can say, "ok glass, share with...".

Comment: @androiddeveloper it helps if your application benefits from all hands free operation.

Comment: i see. so instead of waiting for glass to listen, you just continue talking and it will do what you want. isn't it a bit problematic (technically), since the "ok glass" (isn't it "ok google" btw?) could be a part of a sentence? for example in order to explain how it works?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Contextual voice commands are not yet supported by the platform, feel free to file a feature request in our [issues tracker](https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/list).

**UPDATE**: as mentioned in the comments and the other answer, contextual voice commands are now part of the platform for Immersion: https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice#contextual_voice_commands

Comment: I have added a request to ask for Contextual Voice Commands https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273

Comment: Could we customize the look of the voice intent?  So it looks like our card but we can response to voice commands?

Comment: Seems like Contextual Voice commands are now available per: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273#c25

Answer (score 5):

As of XE18.1 and GDK Preview 19, contextual voice commands are available in the GDK. Documentation is available at https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/voice.