# Can you customize the Google Glass speech recognition view?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

Can you customize the Google Glass [speech recognition view](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/starting-glassware#starting_speech_recognition)?

For example adding text above "Start speaking"?

If not, is there a way to capture voice input within an Activity for a user to say "Next" to have them advance to the next screen?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you fire an intent to use the google glass speech recognition api. So if you can edit and make changes to that activity and its xml templates. I have only worked with calling it via intent and importing a project.

Comment: Also the second question, I believe is a second issue which the glass team called contextual voice which is in the issue tracker. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20133577/adding-the-ok-glass-contextual-voice-menu-within-an-immersion-activity

Answer (score 1):

Contextual Voice (or something like it) seems to be available now per: https://code.google.com/p/google-glass-api/issues/detail?id=273#c25, #28 and #29. I'm using it now to accomplish what I need for the most part.

Comment: This broke with XE17 :(

Answer (score 1):

Now you can simply customize the text with this code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "YOUR MESSAGE HERE");
startActivityForResult(intent, SPEECH_REQUEST);
```

I hope it will be fine for you.